# mailgun-js: how to get stats on a tag?

Tags: mailgun

I want to get statistics on a Mailgun tag and I follow the docs: https://bojand.github.io/mailgun-js/#/api/tags

This works fine:

```
const info = await mailgun.tags('my-tag').info()
```

(it returns `{ tag, description, 'first-seen', 'last-seen' }`)

This also works:

```
const info = await mailgun.tags('my-tag').stats().aggregates().countries().list()
```

However, this:

```
const info = await mailgun.tags('my-tag').stats().info()
```

gives me:

```
Error: Missing parameters.
  at constructor.impl (my-app/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/build.js:55:17)
  at callback (my-app/node_modules/promisify-call/index.js:32:8)
  at my-app/node_modules/with-callback/index.js:39:7
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at withCallback (my-app/node_modules/with-callback/index.js:5:10)
  at promisifyCall (my-app/node_modules/promisify-call/index.js:28:10)
  at constructor.promisifed [as info] (my-app/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/build.js:105:14)
  at routeGetEmailStats (my-app/server/routes/email.js:192:59)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to to pass `event` as a parameter:

```
const info = await mailgun.tags('my-tag').stats().info({ event: ['delivered', 'opened', 'clicked', 'failed'] })
```

First I got it to work with `mailgun.get`:

```
const info = await mailgun.get(`/MY-MAILGUN-DOMAIN/tags/my-tag/stats`, { event: ['delivered', 'opened', 'clicked', 'failed'] })
```

Also, `mailgun.get` provided a better error message which helped me.